# Active Directory PowerShell

Tags: powershell

For PowerShell 2.0

I mean to manage Active Directory using Windows PowerShell. I have an application server where in I have installed RSAT with ActiveDirectory PowerShell CmdLets. When I run a command for AD cmdlet, for example; Get-ADOrganizationalUnit it gives me an error message.
'Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running.'

Upon researching I found 2 articles:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2852 - Install AD Management Gateway Service.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/29/use-active-directory-cmdlets-with-powershell-to-find-users.aspx

Question:

Is it really necessary to install AD Management Gateway Service as All the Domain Controllers are running on Windows Server 2003?

Is there any other EASY :) way to query AD like AD CmdLets? I know that Quest is another route but I cant use it as I am prohibited to install any 3rd Party CMDLETS.

Thanks in advance,

Rajiv

Comment: This Question is related to Programming as it is directly related to setting up the environment. A programming environment is very essential before he/she begins coding.

Comment: @Rajiv That's very fuzzy logic. That's like saying that a question about construction of airplane wings is related to skydiving and is on-topic for a discussion forum about skydiving, because you have to construct airplane wings in order to build the vehicle from which skydiving begins. Perhaps a question about ergonomic keyboard design would also be appropriate for StackOverflow because programming involves a lot of typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it really necessary to install AD Management Gateway Service as All the Domain Controllers are running on Windows Server 2003?

**Yes.**

> Is there any other EASY :) way to query AD like AD CmdLets? I know that Quest is another route but I cant use it as I am prohibited to install any 3rd Party CMDLETS.

The Easy way would be the Quest module but if you can't install it I suggest to play with .net class

[system.directoryservices.accountmanagement](http://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2008/05/25/system-directoryservices-accountmanagement/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is possible to use the ADSI interface?

check out the following article:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx

/Fredrik